# Get all subsites in site collection and all lists in each subsites

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sub-site, sharepoint-rest-api

I need  to call multiple  rest calls for getting the information  from the SharePoint Online. 
Iam using  java script.

First I need to get all subsites and then I need to get all lists information  from each subsite. I managed  to get the information  using REST calls. I need to know if there is a best practice for calling multiple  REST calls.

I need to ensure that after  successful completion  of  one API call, the subsites call,  I can then make the lists call.

Can anyone  suggest best approach  with sample code if possible? I need to call multiple  get calls one by one  after successful  completion  previous  call. Currently  i am storing all the subsite  urls  in an array and   doing for each  on the array  to store list urls in another  array.

Comment: Here's the link that shows how to chain multiple REST calls. --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16026942/how-do-i-chain-three-asynchronous-calls-using-jquery-promises

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of comments

- `success` CallBacks are 2016, even jQuerys $.ajax has supported `.done` and `.fail` Promises for ages
- using async=false solves your async problem but now your whole page and the rest of the script are waiting for those (rather slow) SP API calls
  Learn to work with [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (requires a Polyfill for IE, because it doesn't support the Web Standard yet)
  or use jQuerys [non-standard](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) implementation of Promises
- Nowadays you don't want to stick jQuery.ajax all over the place, Microsofts new SharePoint Framework uses its own HttpClient
  So you want to call jQuery only from ONE function, so you can easily refactor
- jQuerys `$.each` function can be replaced with standard JavaScript.. faster.. shorter
- The Web endpoint already contains information about its Lists
  But they are __deferred,
  [image]
  So you can use that uri (when you go the multiple calls & Promises route)

OR.. [it is all standard OData](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/)...
tell the Server to **include it with ?$expand=Lists**

[image]

Code will then be something like:

*I am not using jQuery myself but HTML5 Promises,

so you have to add the .when code yourself*

```
console.clear();
function ajaxCall(endpoint, doneFunction) {
    $.ajax({
        url: endpoint,

        //ONLY USE  async=false FOR A QUICK FIX
        //WHEN YOU DON'T CARE EVERYTHING HALTS TILL THE REST CALL IS FINISHED
        //WHEN YOU DON'T CARE ABOUT USING PROMISES
        //WHEN YOU ARE *NOT* A PROGRAMMER WHO WANTS TO DO IT RIGHT
        async:false,  

        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    })
        .done(doneFunction)
        .fail(function(err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        );
}
var siteLists = {};
ajaxCall(
    _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Webs?$expand=Lists",
    function (data) {
        data.d.results.forEach(function (web, webidx) {
            siteLists[web.Title] = web;
            console.log(webidx,web.Title,web.Lists);
        })
    });

console.info(siteLists);
```

- If you want the List**Items** you make it:

  ```
   _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Webs?$expand=Lists,Lists/Items",
  ```

You will sure notice a wait then

iREST

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code you are looking for..

I have tried to fetch all the subsites in one call and then made call to each subsite to fetch all list items..

so number of calls is 1 + No. of subsites in your site collection

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/webs/?$select=title,ServerRelativeUrl",
    type: "GET",        
    async:false,        
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.d.results,function(ind,val){
            console.log("Site : " + val.Title);
            console.log('Lists');
            getLists(val.ServerRelativeUrl);
        })
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
function getLists(ServerRelativeUrl){
    $.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl +"/" + ServerRelativeUrl +"/_api/Web/Lists",
    type: "GET",
    async:false,        
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data.d.results,function(ind,val){
        //  debugger;
            console.log("        "+ val.Title);
        })
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will try the above code and update  you

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are working with javascript.

You can achieve this by putting the code for next rest call in the success handler of the previous rest call. 
You should store the current index from the array in some global variable.
So, you would need the function that calls the rest api for the current url from array, and when it finishes, the success handler function should make the lists rest call for that subsite. The lists rest call function should have the success handler that increases the current array index and calls the first function again.
The calls should finish when you get to the end of your array.

More about rest calls, and examples of succes handler functions can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022.aspx).

Comment: Hi  Damjan Tomic thanks for the reply. Iam using java script.  Can you  please  provide  any   sample code please